# What tools are available for EEG analysis on the R platform?

Tags: measurement, methodology, eeg, statistics, data

I'm starting some EEG studies on attention, and would really like to use R for preprocessing (filtering/artifact rejection), visualization, and analysis, but I can find very little in the way of tools. If there isn't a standalone package, what packages might be useful?

Things I want to do:

- Condition categorization according to events, and comparing all subsequent analyses by condition
- Power spectral density in specific frequency bands (SMR, theta, beta, alpha, etc.)
- Event-related potentials
- LORETA (low-resolution electromagnetic tomography)

Comment: Checkout the package listing:<br>
<a href="http://cran.rstudio.com/">http://cran.rstudio.com/</a>. It might help people to help you, if you clarify what you are trying to accomplish with R and EEG data.

Comment: Why do you want to use R?

Comment: Because the documentation & community is better for R than Matlab, and because I don't have to worry about budget for licenses on R.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Antoine Tremblay has just released an advanced analysis toolbox: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/psyp.12299/abstract

It's missing about half the features on your list, although fundamentally, spectral density is a simple task and LORETA is a stand-alone package anyways (although similar approaches, e.g. general CSD estimation, are implemented in many packages). Basically, once you got the EEG data read into R and cleaned of artifacts, ERPs (simple averaging) and spectra are fairly basic tasks and LORETA is an external toolbox agnostic of where it's getting its data from.

Alternatively, I would propose to use either one of the two standard MATLAB-based solutions (EEGLAB or Fieldtrip), or MNE in one of its iterations (e.g. the one in Python). All of these will handle the tasks you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on visualization?  Creating graph arrays for 24 channels of ERP or EEG can be very tedious, and I bet somebody's done it before.

Comment: Butterfly plots, as in fig. 2 in the paper; or means over ROIs and facet wrap ggplot over hemisphere and front/back.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for alternative when I fell on this post. Here are a few others

[eegUtils](https://github.com/craddm/eegUtils) , the same author has a blog that might be of interest to you for further reading [here](https://craddm.github.io/tags/eeg)

I also found [eegAnalysis](https://rdrr.io/cran/eegAnalysis/man/eegAnalysis-package.html) but the last update was in 2014

Finally for ERPs there is [erpR](https://cran.csiro.au/web/packages/erpR/erpR.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness:

1. eegkit, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eegkit/index.html
2. For "historical purposes" perhaps the following could also be of interest, although development seems somewhat stagnant lately: https://rdrr.io/cran/eegAnalysis/